# undefined control sequences for algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

I have some major and some minor issues while using `algorithm2e`.

For major issues, although the package itself defined some controls such as `\input` , `\Fn` etc., but when it comes to use them, I receive and error indicating these controls are not defined.

For minor issues, taking into account the following MWE, first of all the if clause does not have and ending which I wonder how I should fix it and secondly, for each line of comment, there is a weird `;` at the beginning of the line:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{program}
\begin{document}
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}[H]

%\Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
%\Output{A partition of the bitmap}

  \uIf{domain.equals(keyword) AND id=0}{
  \tcc*[r]{occurrence at the root node (first layer)}
      setAttribute(D,PN)\; 
   }\uElseIf{domain.equals(keyword) AND $id\not=0$}{ \tcc*[r]{occurrence at the second layer}
        setAttribute(D,SL)\;
  }
  \uElseIf{path.equals(keyword) AND id=0}{ \tcc*[r]{occurrence at path of root node}
    setAttribute($P_a$, PN)\;
    }

 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), package [algorithm2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) uses macro `\SetKwInOut` to define `\Input` and `\Output`. The following example also uses `\If` instead of `\uIf` to get the end markers (not sure, whether I have the question correctly). Also normal comments are used to get rid of the semicolon.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{program}
\begin{document}
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
  \BlankLine

  \uIf{domain.equals(keyword) AND id=0}{
    \tcc{occurrence at the root node (first layer)}
    setAttribute(D,PN)\;
   }\uElseIf{domain.equals(keyword) AND $id\not=0$}{
      \tcc{occurrence at the second layer}
      setAttribute(D,SL)\;
  }
  \ElseIf{path.equals(keyword) AND id=0}{
    \tcc{occurrence at path of root node}
    setAttribute($P_a$, PN)\;
    }

 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Right aligned comments are not my taste. The indentation of source code
provides information about the structure, this is destroyed by comments
moved to the right.

The example inserts `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` to move the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{program}
\newcommand\HFilll{\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}}
\begin{document}
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
  \BlankLine

  \uIf{domain.equals(keyword) AND id=0}{
    \HFilll\tcc{occurrence at the root node (first layer)}
    setAttribute(D,PN)\;
   }\uElseIf{domain.equals(keyword) AND $id\not=0$}{
      \HFilll\tcc{occurrence at the second layer}
      setAttribute(D,SL)\;
  }
  \ElseIf{path.equals(keyword) AND id=0}{
    \HFilll\tcc{occurrence at path of root node}
    setAttribute($P_a$, PN)\;
    }

 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I see. How about the other issues?

Comment: but if i want to show that first if-clause is the condition that if it is not satisfied, the rest of if-clauses wont be triggered, I'm afraid this new look will make reader not aware of this.

Comment: @lonesome Maybe, you take a look into the documentation? I do not know, what you like and what you want to have as result.

Comment: There should be only one `end` which corresponds to first `if` followed by `else if` nested in between,

Comment: Where did you change?

Comment: @lonesome Click on `edited ... ago` to get the edit history.

Comment: Isnt there by any chance a solution to the comment issue while it is justified at right margin?

Comment: I see. Here is an upvote for the effort and solution~